# Could not find an overload for “init” that accepts the supplied arguments (swift)

Tags: swift

It worked in swift beta4 and now i have GM version
but this error says hello 
how can i solve this problem?

"Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments" in 2 parts

```
var timer = NSTimer()
var counter : Double = 7.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    labelCounter.text = String(counter)       <- error here
}

@IBOutlet weak var labelCounter: UILabel!

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func startCounterPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer.invalidate()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func update()   {
    sth cool
    }

@IBAction func pauseCounterPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer.invalidate()
}

@IBAction func stopCounterPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer.invalidate()
    counter = 7.0
    labelCounter.text = String(counter)           <- error here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String` class overload `init` method for `double`.

```
let s = NSString(format: "%.2f", counter)
```

Comment: And the String type has the same init: let s = String(format: "%.2f", counter)